# what's wrong with this Z index

Tags: css

When I click the button on top right of the green box (box on the left): http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/211/

Why does the gray area not cover the connector?

My connector has z-index of 18, the gray area has z-index of 19, shouldn't it overlay the connector?

```
._jsPlumb_connector { z-index:18; }

.info{
    background-color:#cfcfcf;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    z-index:19;
    color:black; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch, read up on how `z-index` relates to the `position` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` or `position:absolute` to `.info` styles.

Comment: A solution with no explanation isn't worth a whole lot.  Teach op to fish!